# What more is needed to permanently suspend a user for systematic, intentional, and planned plagiarism across SE?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, account-suspension

In the last few hours, I have raised five (5) flags in SO and five (5) flags in Data Science SE (DSSE), all of them concerning systematic plagiarism (and attempts of) by a specific user.

In brief:

- Said user sees an SO question, posts an exact copy to DSSE, gets an answer there, then comes back here and posts this answer word by word (including a clarification in the comments) without attribution; FWIW, they don't not even bother to accept (or even upvote) the DSSE answer they plagiarize, while they prompt the OP in SO to "*tick my answer as correct*" (and end up with 3 upvotes).
- User does the exact same thing as above with another SO question - only difference is that now  they accept the answer offered at DSSE (no upvote though); plagiarized answer at SO gets accepted and 3 upvotes.
- User sees a DSSE question, posts an exact copy here at SO, gets an answer, then goes back at DSSE and posts this answer again word by word without attribution. Again FWIW, and in contrast with the relatively short answers of the previous bullet, this answer is a *long* and comprehensive one, including quotes and code snippets.
- User sees a question in SO with a bounty of 50, posts an exact copy to DSSE without attribution, but unfortunately (!) they don't get any answers there, so the act stops here
- User does the exact same thing as in the last bullet above with **three (3)** more SO questions, this time without bounties; again, no answers at DSSE, hence no further acts here at SO

With one justifiable exception, all these flags here and at DSSE were found helpful and accepted.

The result?

- At DSSE, user gets only a **temporal** suspension for plagiarism for **7 days**
- Here at SO, **nothing**; user maintains their ~ 650 rep, and they are let loose to leave comments around, accusing me of "*taking advantage of your reputation*"...

So, to break down the question in the title:

- Isn't it clear that here we have a case of systematic, intentional, recurring, and planned plagiarism practice, aiming at gaining undeserved reputation across SE, which, had it gone unnoticed, could have gone on for who knows how long for? Or is it just my idea?
- If yes, what more is needed in order to permanently suspend such a user?

And to conclude, will I find myself eventually in the defensive, trying to complain for retaliation to people unwilling to listen?

Just asking... Because if I find myself in such a situation in the future, it would be obvious that I have done something *very* wrong...

**UPDATE**

Buried in the comments in Rob's answer below (and while I still keep on finding similar plagiarism cases in the said user's posts, including from sources outside SE), it turns out that the said user got a **written warning** (by email). Seems that these mods at DSSE are extremists indeed...

All in all, the question boils down to a definition issue: **what exactly counts as first offense?** It is the first time one does something wrong, or just the first time one gets *caught*, despite the fact that one may have multiple violations? Common sense suggests the former, however mods here have handled the situation according to the latter..

Comment: Were these custom flags you raised, giving full details?

Comment: I mean... unless the flags are getting declined.... i'd suggest just waiting. I'd assume the flag volume here is much larger.

Comment: @TRiG Yes, and they were "linked" ("*please see my previous `X` custom flags*"); I don't have any serious doubt that mods have the full picture (Brad Larson accepted the first 2 flags here)

Comment: Also mind that two different mods are handling these flags, since "Mod on SO" couldn't handle your flags on DSSE and vice versa. So their decisions on which action should be taken can differ.

Comment: FYI people almost never get permabanned for a first offense.  IF this person continues to misbehave after their current suspension they'll get longer and longer time outs until finally shown the door.

Comment: @DanNeely well, first he has to get banned, which hasn't happened here, at least yet! And it is arguable if all this behavior can count as one single (hence first) offense, right?

Comment: Ah, so the rabbit hole is deeper.  It would be nice if I could blacklist such a user so I would not see his questions anymore.

Comment: I don't want to disappoint you, but even suspending won't help much if staff will helpfully merge all accounts created to circumvent the suspension into the main account and the user can just continue using the network as if nothing happened https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334398/can-a-suspended-user-still-post-and-vote

Comment: @samcarter thanks; but it's not a matter of me being disappointed or not, of course, neither it is to play the police detectives or something

Answer (score 13):

Firstly, we don't do permanent suspensions on Stack Exchange except for very extreme cases and even then, the suspensions still have a set (albeit long) duration. Suspensions over a year cannot be applied by elected moderators.

The moderators on Stack Overflow tend to follow the following escalation process for problematic users (with a bit of wiggle room for moderator discretion):

1. Warning. This is a message sent via Stack Overflow and via email, and will be permanently attached to the account for future moderators to view. This step is not visible to the public - which means that a user may have been warned, but the flagger may incorrectly believe no action was taken.
2. 7 day suspension
3. 30 day suspension
4. 1 year suspension

We rarely jump straight to suspensions without a warning, as we've found that warning first results in a better response from the user - having them more willing to change their ways. If a user continues the same problematic behaviour after being warned, that is when suspensions will begin to be applied.

Comment: Kindly define "*very extreme*"

Comment: @desertnaut Death threats, repeatedly posting extreme abuse/bigotry, chronic suspension evader, and so on.

Comment: Oh... OK, I thought we were still talking about plagiarism. In the meanwhile,  since I finished writing the post above, I have raised 1 more similar flag here and 2 more at DSSE, yet the user has yet to be banned, even temporarily, here; do you plan to just "warn" him?

Comment: @desertnaut Your original flags were handled by another moderator, and yes, the process written above was followed. I handled your most recent flag - but as their post happened in the past, it wouldn't make sense to escalate further *now*. If they continue to post plagiarism, please flag again, and we'll escalate as necessary

Comment: With all due respect, I think you are kidding me... :(

Comment: As written above, we've found users are more receptive to feedback from warnings than a suspension. We're not in the business of punishing users, we're in the business of cleaning up messes and guiding people to become more productive members of the community. If they continue after being explicitly warned, *that's* when we need to take further steps. If they don't, well then, I'd call that a success

Comment: None of *us* is in the business of punishing people, but certainly at least one of us (that would be me, of course) seems, at the end of the day, to have done something very wrong. I honestly hope you are right, but if I start getting retaliation downvotes, I will kindly ping you here, hoping that you will not claim that it is "another story" or "that's life at SO"...

Comment: @desertnaut: Even if we did suspend the user here, that's not going to stop them from seeing and stealing content from here. A network suspension isn't going to help much either, unless the staff decide not to welcome them to even *read* the network anymore. But that's up to their discretion. The most we can do is escalate.

Comment: @BoltClock not sure what your point is exactly in this hypothetical extreme scenario; steal content *why*? To post it to Quora? It is apparent from the pattern (because that's what it is, a *pattern*, not a single unfortunate case) that the motive has been the SE rep system; take this out, and there is no more reason to steal anything... Beyond my initial question for permanent removal, I certainly understand the escalation, but... a *warning*?

Comment: @desertnaut: My point is we can't do anything on our (stackoverflow.com's) end but ask them to knock it off. Suspending might send a little bit of a sterner message, but it's only actually going to enforce anything when issued on the other site, not here.

Comment: @BoltClock sorry, I lost you; the other site??

Comment: @desertnaut: Oh, damn it. So the plagiarism is occurring on *both* sites. Then I don't understand why each site is handling this inconsistently.

Comment: Both sites - both ways...

Comment: Different sites, different moderators. For all we know the mods on DataScience had warned that user before and/or had other additional reasons to suspend. Don’t assume you know the full picture here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters forget DSSE, the real question here is: **what exactly counts as first offense?** It is the first time one does something wrong, or just the first time one gets *caught*, despite the fact that one may have multiple violations? Common sense suggests the former, however here you have handled the situation according to the latter...

Comment: @MartijnPieters and if I have been warned here and then get caught plagiarizing in, say, Math SE, is it really my first time? How far Math SE is from SO, really?

Comment: @desertnaut There is no black and white answer here, and is moderators have leeway to take different actions in different situations. However, other sites have their own moderators and actions on another site are under the “jurisdiction” of other moderators. For me, everything before us mods finding problematic behaviour we want to see corrected is a first offence; just because the user has plagiarised multiple posts doesn’t change that. That doesn’t mean I won’t hand out a suspension just because it’s a first offence.

Comment: @desertnaut and moderators do often share details of user behaviour with other site moderators, if we see a pattern repeated on another site. However, as other mods have said: our primary goal is to keep our sites clean, not to hand out punishments. I completely agree that behaviour like this is pretty appalling, but *you have to accept how we handle this*. We don’t give out suspensions just because you feel the behaviour is heinous and deserves stronger punishment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry Martijn, I don't get what you mean by "*For me, everything before us mods finding problematic behaviour we want to see corrected is a first offence*" (everything?); and we are discussing here, right? The issue arguably is not my feelings... And if I **have** to accept how you are handling this and should not discuss it, kindly confirm it, and I promise to stop...

Comment: What I mean is: if we have caught a user plagiarising, their total body of plagiarised posts *up to the point we contact them* is one offence. They may or may not have known that what they were doing was wrong.  I personally have still suspended users on first offence if I find exceptionally large numbers of plagiarism, or that our community has been telling them in comments that it’s bad and they then tried to obfuscate their copies, or have been using sock puppets, etc. But multiple plagiarised posts doesn’t count as multiple offences.

Comment: Personally, I only send a warning once I find at least a *second* instance of plagiarism. Copying a single post is easily cleaned up. The moment I find two, and so know there is a pattern, we know we have a problem that needs correcting for.

Comment: @MartijnPieters appreciate your thoughts and opinion. Still waiting for your kind clarification if I **have** to accept how you are handling this and stop discussing it, as it admittedly sounds very strange (and quite unexpected) in a Meta *discussion*...

Comment: @desertnaut: I just have the feeling you passionately want a certain outcome from all this. I'm not telling you not to discuss this, just trying to manage expectations. Know that we are aware of the user and their antics, and that we are handling it. Also, we can't go into details on individual cases.

Comment: Perhaps update your answer with some of the information from comments (e.g. elaboration of "very extreme")?

Comment: @desertnaut: It is rampant on Quora. Yesterday I flagged [3](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-WordPress-comments-plugin/answer/Abhishek-Deshpande-63) [answers](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-free-comment-plugin-for-WordPress/answer/Keshav-Infotech-2) on the same Quora question; each contained wholesale copies of (3 different) blog posts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters or it might just be that your feeling is wrong, and "*passionate*" is the completely wrong word here. Thank you for trying to manage (i.e. lower) my expectations, but it's funny how you have seemingly managed to get *me* in the defensive, as if *I* am the wrongdoer in this whole story; for spending my precious time in order to expose this nasty situation in two SE sites with ten (10) flags, *you are very welcome*...

Comment: @desertnaut: sorry if I made you feel you were in the wrong, that was not my intention. I can't express, ever, how thankful I *really* am for you, and our community as a whole, in helping us find cases of plagiarism. Plagiarism clean-ups are largely manual affairs, so I'm always **extremely** grateful for people helping us find every single individual case of copying!

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I don't know if Quora tracks flag rankings for accounts, but if they do, I surely must have a huge ranking value there. I regularly handle plagiarism here on SO and then find *newer* copies over on Quora, which I flag every time. Granted, they also have handled my flags diligently, with the post disappearing within minutes, often!

Comment: I guess it's not the case anymore. I just got directly suspended without warning or anything for my first offense (editing wayback machine apparently is deserving direct suspension) in meta.se