# Is plagiarizing content from SO by SO users not a concern for SO?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, plagiarism, attribution

NOTE: Question is completely different from the linked one (I am the author of both), and has to do very specifically with the two flags discussed in-text, which were not at all part of the discussion there.

In the process of uncovering a systematic plagiarism case between SO and Data Science Stack Exchange (DSSE), briefly summarized [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391201/what-more-is-needed-to-permanently-suspend-a-user-for-systematic-intentional-a), I came upon some rather peculiar cases, where the user had plagiarized **questions** from SO; quoting from the linked post:

> - User sees a question in SO with a bounty of 50, posts an exact copy to DSSE without attribution, but unfortunately (!) he doesn't get any
>     answers there, so the act stops here
> - User does the exact same thing as in the last bullet above with **three (3)** more SO questions, this time without bounties; again, no answers at DSSE, hence no further acts here at SO

For two (2) out of these total four (4) posts, in addition to the respective flags raised at DSSE, I opened flags at SO as well; here they are (with names redacted):

> Question has been copied & posted to Data Science SE by **another user**, [REDACTED], possibly trying to get an answer there in order to win the bounty here: [LINK]. Such behavior by the said user seems **systematic** - pls see my 2 previous custom flags

and

> Question has been copied & posted to Data Science SE by another user, [REDACTED]: [LINK]. Such behavior by the said user seems **systematic** - pls see my 3 previous custom flags

The reception of these two flags, respectively, was:

> declined - Please flag this *on datascience.se*, if they were to plagiarise DataScience.SE answers *here*, we'll deal with that *then*.

and

> helpful - It would be much more productive for you to flag this on the datascience site. We can deal with their exploits *here*, not with their actions there.

The detailed status (declined/helpful) of the flags is not my concern here, because essentially they both claim the same thing:

*If an SO user plagiarizes us somewhere else, it's not **our** concern, and it should be just reported there, **not here***.

Let me clarify here, before proceeding, that this discussion makes sense under two assumptions, without which the flags above are obviously meaningless:

- The offender is an SO user
- The questions themselves (especially well-written and well-researched questions, with reproducible examples, code, plots etc) are themselves content, too

---

Given the above, I must say I find the verbal response to both flags puzzling; as I see it, such plagiarizing of SO stuff by an SO user should indeed be a concern for SO itself, **independently** of what concern it may be for the "receiving" part of the plagiarism (here DSSE); if not anything else, the [Attribution Required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) policy seems crystal clear on that.

So, what am I missing here? And what should I do in a similar situation in the future, other than flagging as I did?

Comment: Raise a flag. there's literally nothing us regular users can do about it.

Comment: @KevinB that's exactly what I did, and I was practically told that I shouldn't have

Comment: What if this user was plagiarizing content here to another, entirely separate site? Say, like Quora?  What recourse do we have?  Treat other sites the same way, even if they're in-network.  Plagiarization is a problem for the target site; even if we were to suspend the user here, that wouldn't solve the problem.  You can't stop someone from reading the site, after all.  DS.SE can bring the hammer down, and prevent them from posting more plagiarized content there.  And vice versa, when they do so here.

Comment: @desertnaut then your job is done. move on

Answer (score 8):

> If an SO user plagiarizes us somewhere else, it's not our concern, and it should be just reported there, not here.

That's correct. It is a jurisdictional issue.

We are an online Q&A site, not a reform school. As much as we might wish we could do so, it is not our job to teach people life skills. Furthermore, we can only moderate what happens on *this site*, and we only have the jurisdiction to punish people for actions they take on *this site*.

It is not clear what you would want a Stack Overflow moderator to do about actions that are taken on some other website.

Consider an example: Someone plagiarizes a Stack Overflow Q&A on Medium. You notice this, and you flag it for moderator attention. What do you want a Stack Overflow moderator to do in that case?

- Do you want us to **report it to Medium?** Well, you could/should have done that yourself, so that doesn't require moderator intervention. Stack Overflow moderators have no special powers when it comes to Medium, so there's no real advantage in escalating this to us.
- Do you want us to have a conversation with the user(s) who wrote the original Q&A—*i.e.*, **the victims of plagiarism?** Well, I guess we *could* do that (*"Look, your contributions here have been plagiarized on Medium. There's not much we can do, but you might want to issue Medium a take-down notice and/or start legal proceedings."*), but why should we? Equally as importantly, why couldn't you, by leaving an advisory comment underneath one of the posts? Again, acting on this doesn't require moderator privileges.
- In fact, what it sounds like you want us to do is to **hunt down the Stack Overflow account of the plagiarist** and take action against that account. However, we are not going to do that. (In this case, you apparently hunted it down for us, but that doesn't change the response.) As stated above, we moderate Stack Overflow. We don't moderate users, and we darn sure don't moderate the Internet. If we take actions against users, such as warning them or suspending their account, it's going to be for actions that they take *on this website*, for which we have jurisdiction to act, actions for which we have full documentation and thorough proof.

In this case, the only material difference is that the plagiarism was happening within the Stack Exchange network. Stack Overflow moderators do have access to a backchannel that allows us to communicate with moderators on other Stack Exchange sites. I don't know the details, but the moderator(s) who handled your flags may well have reached out to the Data Science moderators. But, again, there's no need to involve a Stack Overflow moderator. You have access to an equivalent private channel to the Data Science moderators: raise flags on their site.

> …as I see it, such plagiarizing of SO stuff by an SO user should indeed be a concern for SO itself, independently of what concern it may be for the "receiving" part of the plagiarism (here DSSE); if not anything else, the [Attribution Required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) policy seems crystal clear on that.

Yes, it is a big deal. Every one of the moderators you've spoken to on Meta has had a reaction somewhere between annoyed and outraged. This is a clear violation of the Attribution Required policy, and indeed of the license agreement. But Stack Overflow moderators are not lawyers; we're not license police. We're not going to go around the Internet issuing take-down requests or filing injunctions. This is not our job. We moderate *this* community. Even if we wanted to, we simply cannot react to abuses perpetrated *on* this community from without. We have neither the jurisdiction, capability, or resources.

Importantly, the fact that you had a flag declined doesn't necessarily mean that you did anything wrong. If you see problematic content in the future, you should continue to bring it to moderator attention via flags. We appreciate all reports of plagiarism, and we do take them very seriously. Realistically, though, there are limits to our power, and you will get more bang for your buck by escalating to the appropriate parties. The only thing you have done wrong is expecting for moderators to take prescribed action that is publicly visible to you.

Comment: "flag declined doesn't mean that you did anything wrong"???? How is one is expected to learn what to flag and what not to flag then? Ask about every flag on meta? Does it also imply that "flag accepted doesn't mean that you did everything right"?

Comment: You have to read the decline message; you can't just look at the state. Declined might just mean, "the flag is valid, but a moderator chose not to take any action". It's like a downvote: it's a signal you *may* have done something wrong, but doesn't necessarily mean you need to modify your post/behavior.

Comment: Thank you Cody, although I confess I cannot understand your *tone*; I don't want you (or anyone else, for that matter) to do anything - I just posted a very simple and clear *question* (*"What am I missing?* and *what should I do in a similar situation in the future?*). You have certainly answered them both, but I cannot formally accept your answer, as you sound like yelling at and attacking me, on the grounds of your *hypothesis* of "what it sounds like I want you to do", and I regret to say that this is neither accepted nor appreciated, much less from a moderator with your history...

Comment: And if indeed "*The only thing you have done wrong is expecting for moderators to take prescribed action*" holds (no "sounds like" here), I am happy because it doesn't seem I have done anything wrong, since I didn't hold any such expectations - as I said, it was nothing more than a *question* seeking *guidance*...

Comment: @desertnaut FWIW you write in quite aggressive tone yourself, with **bold** words that can read like yelling and attacking (And to me it definitely sounds like that [in your other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391201/what-more-is-needed-to-permanently-suspend-a-user-for-systematic-intentional-a)). I'm surprised that you take offense at the tone of this answer when your own posts sound much harsher, at least to me.

Comment: @sth duly noted; bold is a necessary evil (somehow we need to give emphasis sometimes), and my issue here has absolutely nothing to do with the bold parts of the answer. Appreciate the feedback though

Comment: You aren’t the first person to accuse me of having an accusatory tone, and you surely won’t be the last. I confess I don’t really understand why, and I can assure you that no offense or attack was intended. It is entirely possible that I’ve misread your intentions or goals. I’m not good at reading minds. But you’ve been *very* insistent here, both in comments associated with the previous question, and in posting a follow-up. If you have some additional motivations you’d like me to appreciate, feel free to let me know. I added the last paragraph to clarify that we *always* appreciate it...

Comment: ...when users raise flags in good faith to let us know of things they come across that they find concerning. If you don’t pay any attention to any of this, and you keep raising flags on plagiarism, I assure you that no one will be angry with you for doing your part to keep the site clean. As a final note, I’m not sure what you meant by, “a moderator with your history.” What history is that? A history of being a call-it-like-I-see-it, persistent, pain in the backside? Yeah, that’s me. It cuts both ways. :-) @desert

Comment: This post could benefit from covering the fact that moderators do have a unique conduit to employees (who *are* in a position to reach out to Medium as a license enforcer with standing) and whether that's an appropriate avenue for passing such notifications up the chain.

Comment: Worth noting, however, that Stack Overflow is a *licensee*, not the licensor, @Tyler. They can always make a request of a third party, but I’m not sure they’d have any more standing than you or I. The original poster is who’d have the most legal standing, as far as I understand, with the caveat that I’m not a lawyer and wouldn’t admit it if I were. While mods could escalate this to employees, I really don’t think we would, realistically. But that’s a conversation that we can have. Does the community think that the standing policy described here needs to be amended?

Comment: Sorry Cody; beginning your answer with "*I don't know why you're having such a difficult time swallowing this*" (now edited out by @TylerH), before even starting to explain, is "darn sure" not appreciated. Reading words is arguably better and safer than trying to read intentions, goals, or minds, especially if, as you say, you have reasons to believe that you may be not that good at the latter. "Darn sure", nobody asked you why you don't moderate or police the Internet; the last para of your answer would be more than enough in itself to answer the question here.

Comment: We all have our history; to stay consistent with mine, I can no longer sit here, getting intimidated and dismissed beforehand on the basis of some hypothetical motivations that I may or may not have, while having to listen to how much my actions are appreciated (thanks for the edit, BTW). I guess it's a good time to leave SO for good; so goodbye, and thanks for all the fish...

Comment: That is a major overreaction to having a flag rejected and feeling dismissed by a moderator. I’m sorry that you were offended by my wording. As I said before, it was not intentional. I wrote this answer right after reopening this question, so surely my impressions were colored by the fact that you had seen it fit to ask this as a follow-up. It was quite clear that you were having trouble accepting or understanding Rob’s answer to the previous question. I wasn’t meaning to condemn or insult, just expressing that I must be missing something, given the huge gap. Obviously I respect you. @des

Comment: 1) The fact that "*The detailed status (declined/helpful) of the flags is not my concern here*" was clear and explicit in the question itself; 2) there were also two explicit assumptions, which render your two first bullets irrelevant to the question. 3) the question was not what *you* should do, it was clearly what should *I* do. As I said, kindly try to read, not guess or imagine... :(

Comment: With due respect, this policy is ridiculous. It has nothing whatsoever to do with SO not being a “reform school”. A SO user is caught intentionally abusing the system and SO policy, as stated by you, is to do nothing. Uhm? — This is *apart from the fact* that DSSE is obviously not Medium, it’s very much part of the same network as SO.

Comment: Before leaving, as you and the community are certainly entitled to an explanation... (1/5)

Comment: Verbal assurances  of appreciation and respect are of course a dime a dozen; such attitudes are actually tested in practice. So, in practice, turns out you didn't bother to actually read my specific question (in your last comment, you still think that the issue is a flag rejection), preferring instead to answer a different one that you thought I must in fact be asking under the hood; in doing so, you have actually depicted me as some mysterious guy with unclear motivations, who is seriously wondering (and actually asking) why you, SO mods, don't moderate and police the whole Internet. (2/5)

Comment: In other words, you have ridiculed me, and the fact that your answer goes on and on wondering what "do you want", bullet after bullet, only adds to the picture. Far from respectful and appreciative, this attitude is insulting and, I regret to say, perhaps even borderline immoral. (3/5)

Comment: If you were "*just expressing that I must be missing something, given the huge gap*", as you claim, you have hidden it very well, as it is nowhere to be seen in your answer; if my question was unclear, you should have asked for clarification; if you thought that the question was why you don't moderate the Internet, you should have closed it as off-topic. And if I chose to come back for more after you had answered the specific question as written, this decision was mine to made, and you should not have taken it beforehand in my name, much less acting upon it and depicting me as you did. (4/5)

Comment: To be clear, my decision to leave is not solely upon you here, but, you know, there is always a last straw that breaks the camel's back; talking about appreciation and respect and acting otherwise has become something of an SO feature. So, let me hereby extend my sincere best wishes for the future to you and the community, and, as I already said, goodbye, and thanks for all the fish... (5/5)

Comment: "*Does the community think that the standing policy described here needs to be amended?*" Hard to say with such a niche question whether "the community" will even know to weigh in, on top of the uncertainty regarding the situation: isn't this post just your personal position? Typically moderators are quite explicit when putting forth official moderator team positions.